# Gnuplot for a simple date-time plot

Tags: gnuplot

For this datafile:

```
Server ID,Sponsor,Server Name,Timestamp,Distance,Ping,Download,Upload,Share,IP Address
4981,SELCO,"Shrewsbury, MA",2022-01-19T17:45:00.941297Z,46.02761207264913,16.34,202120227.4774976,5410786.336552021,,66.30.193.6
27031,BELD Broadband,"Braintree, MA",2022-01-19T18:45:01.962140Z,26.98449241976281,17.566,140849719.78516415,5441730.586693773,,66.30.193.6
27031,BELD Broadband,"Braintree, MA",2022-01-19T19:15:01.589345Z,26.98449241976281,17.419,156811809.4210379,5371285.306441804,,66.30.193.6
38849,FiberCast,"Stoddard, NH",2022-01-19T19:45:00.746522Z,106.41034005246897,20.042,215161640.72859222,6086086.612413734,,66.30.193.6
```

I would like a plot with column 7 on the y-axis and column 4 on the x-axis. I would like to make the x-axis go from Jan 21-2022 to Jan-25 2022. I would like the y-axis to be scaled so that 1 is 10^6.

The problems have to do (I think) with the parsing of the date.time and the scaling of the x axis.

```
set datafile separator ","
set key autotitle columnhead
set terminal pdf
set output "speedtest.pdf"
set grid
#set style data lines
#set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%SZ'
#set xrange ["2022-01-19T00:00:00.0Z":"2022-01-24:00:00:00.0Z"]
set xrange [*:*]
plot "test.csv" using 4:7 with linespoints
```

Comment: Do you have somewhere in there a command `set datafile separator comma` so that it knows how to tell where the column breaks are?

Comment: @pitosalas  problem solved? Any response appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethan's `set datafile separator comma` and your `set datafile separator ','` should be equivalent.

Two little details:

- your time format should be `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ` not `%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%SZ`. Find the difference!
- `#` at the beginning of a line makes it a comment. So, remove `#` in the line `#set xdata time`

By the way, you could also just enter `set xrange ["2022-01-19":"2022-01-24"]`. If gnuplot will not find hours, minuts, seconds, I guess it will assume them to be zero.

Check the following slightly modified code.

**Code:**

```
### plotting timedata
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Server ID,Sponsor,Server Name,Timestamp,Distance,Ping,Download,Upload,Share,IP Address
4981,SELCO,"Shrewsbury, MA",2022-01-19T17:45:00.941297Z,46.02761207264913,16.34,202120227.4774976,5410786.336552021,,66.30.193.6
27031,BELD Broadband,"Braintree, MA",2022-01-19T18:45:01.962140Z,26.98449241976281,17.566,140849719.78516415,5441730.586693773,,66.30.193.6
27031,BELD Broadband,"Braintree, MA",2022-01-19T19:15:01.589345Z,26.98449241976281,17.419,156811809.4210379,5371285.306441804,,66.30.193.6
38849,FiberCast,"Stoddard, NH",2022-01-19T19:45:00.746522Z,106.41034005246897,20.042,215161640.72859222,6086086.612413734,,66.30.193.6
EOD

set datafile separator ","
set key autotitle columnhead

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
set xrange ["2022-01-19":"2022-01-24"]   # specific range
set xrange [*:*]                         # autorange
set format x "%H:%M"
set grid

plot $Data using 4:7 w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]